# ¿Cómo puedo buscar archivos y directorios en Node?

Tags: nodejs

Según [este artículo](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-search-files-and-directories-in-nodejs/), con el siguiente código puedo buscar archivos y directorios de una manera recursiva en Node:

```
//This sets up the file finder
var finder = require('findit').find(__dirname);

//This listens for directories found
finder.on('directory', function (dir) {
  console.log('Directory: ' + dir + '/');
});

//This listens for files found
finder.on('file', function (file) {
  console.log('File: ' + file);
});
```

El problema lo tengo en la línea:

```
var finder = require('findit').find(__dirname);
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> TypeError: require(...).find is not a function

La verdad es que no se porque falla.
No parece que ese *find* sea el mismo que [este](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que estás mirando un artículo del año 2011... [Aquí](https://github.com/substack/node-findit) puedes ver la documentación oficial actualizada de la librería.

Simplemente cambia la línea del import

`var finder = require('findit').find(__dirname);`

por

`var finder = require('findit')(process.argv[2] || '.');`